# Using Redux Toolkit's createEntityAdapter for dynamic data grids

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

I have a question about using [`createEntityAdapter`](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createEntityAdapter) from [Redux Toolkit](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/).

I have an application that shows packages and package details using the [AG Grid](https://www.ag-grid.com/) library's [master/detail](https://www.ag-grid.com/documentation/react/master-detail/) functionality.  The app loads the package data in first, then fetches the detail data as each package row is expanded.

I would like to use `createEntityAdapter` to manage the data in a normalized way, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to handle the dynamic nature of the detail grids.  Right now I have a reducer slice that creates a new property every time a set of detail records is loaded. The property key is the `id` of the parent package row, so my `data` slice ends up looking something like this after the package data and the `123` detail data has been loaded:

```
{
  PACKAGES: [{ id: 123, ...otherData }, { id: 124, ...otherData }],
  '123': [{ id: 456, ...otherDetailData }],
}
```

When the user expands the `124` package row, the detail data for that package is fetched and then it looks like this:

```
{
  PACKAGES: [{ id: 123, ...otherData }, { id: 124, ...otherData }],
  '123': [{ id: 456, ...otherDetailData }],
  '124': [{ id: 457, ...otherDetailData }],
}
```

So while I could break out the `PACKAGES` data into its own entity adapter, I can't do the same for the detail grids because I don't know about each of them ahead of time.

I think I'm having a similar problem as the person from [this issue](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-toolkit/issues/799).

I thought about storing all the detail data in a single entity adapter and maintaining another index by the parent `id`, but that seems difficult to keep in sync.

Any ideas?  What is the best practice in this scenario?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the AG Grid data types.  If a "package" and a "detail" are separate entities then it might make sense to handle them separately (could be two properties in the same slice).  If it's an issue of lazily-loaded data then you can restructure each entity into something more custom like an object with properties `meta` and `details`.  I could give you more concrete suggestions if I knew the data structures.  Do you have a repo or a CodeSandbox that you can share?

Comment: @LindaPaiste "Package" isn't specific to AG Grid, it's just the data type I'm dealing with.  Maybe think of it like shipping packages (boxes) and the details are the contents of each box.  The list of boxes is loaded first (I can do that with an entity adapter), then as the user clicks on each box, the contents of that box get fetched and loaded.  It's the second part I'm having trouble mapping to an entity adapter.  Hope that helps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I created and maintain Redux Toolkit, and I actually did do something kinda similar recently with nested entity adapters.

In my case, I needed to maintain these auxiliary data sets as parent items were added or removed.

```
interface ChildrenEntry {
  parentId: ParentId;
  children: EntityState<ChildType>
}

interface ChildrenData {
  parentId: ParentId;
  children: ChildType[];
}

interface NewChildAdded {
  parentId: ParentId;
  child: ChildType;
}

export const childEntriesAdapter = createEntityAdapter<ChildrenEntry>();
export const childrenAdapter = createEntityAdapter<ChildType>();

const initialState = childEntriesAdapter.getInitialState();

const createNewChildEntry = (parentId: ParentId) => ({
  parentId,
  children: childrenAdapter.getInitialState()
});

const childEntriesSlice = createSlice({
  name: "children",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    childEntriesLoaded(state, action: PayloadAction<ChildrenData>) {
      const {parentId, children} = action.payload;
      const childEntry = state.entities[parentId];
      if (childEntry) {
        childrenAdapter.setAll(childEntry.children, children);
      }
    },
    // etc
  },
  extraReducers: builder => {
    builder
      .addCase(parentLoaded, (state, action) => {
        const childEntries = action.payload.map(parent => createNewChildEntry(parent.id));
        childEntriesAdapter.setAll(state, childEntries);
      })
      .addCase(parentDeleted, (state, action) => {
        childEntriesAdapter.removeOne(state, action);
      })
      .addCase(parentAdded, (state, action) => {
        const childEntry = createNewChildEntry(action.payload.id);
        childEntriesAdapter.addOne(state, childEntry);
      });
  }
})
```

There might be a better way to handle this, but it worked sufficiently well for my needs.